# C++: cleaning up code

Tags: c++

I'm going to restart working on a project I put on pause some months ago.

The overall design isn't that bad, don't need to rewrite it from scratch, however there are many things that I don't like, this is mostly because I wrote it in a hurry (no comments and magic numbers everywhere ...) and because the way I use C++ tools is changed (I'd say improved) in the meanwhile (I tend to use much more references, smart pointers, STL, boost, ...).

I think this is the perfect time to clean up that code: doing this will help me getting into it again.

---

I've got two question about cleaning it up:

- What are the things to fix in order to improve a piece of code written in a hurry?
  Things like removing magic numbers, adding comments, divide too big functions into smaller ones and replacing raw pointers/array with smarter objects...
- Is there any tool to help me spot such (and other) dirty pieces?

Comment: 'Is there any tool to help me spot such (and other) dirty pieces?"  Yes:  Eyeballs.

Comment: @James Or <s>slavery</s> "hiring" people to do it for you [for free].

Comment: also check out this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") if you haven't already. If it gets off the ground you can post your code in question up for review and get feedback that way :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPD, the Copy-Paste Detector:  http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html

I use this to look for duplicated code, so I can clean it up.  This helps to follow the DRY principle - Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest fixing magic numbers as one of your first steps. Fixing them should make it more obvious where you've duplicated code, or where a function might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what IDE you are using. Some VS SKU provide great tools like Style and FxCop. There are similar plugins for Eclipse and Idea.

Answer (score 0):

All that you said doesn't sound so bad.

Try to write unit tests for your code, and then you will see how bad it is. If you get close to 100% coverage, your code is in very good shape.
I would start worrying if it is bellow 50-60%, and if it is hard to add new things.

For this you will need a tool to measure the code covered by unit tests.